# Console not printing the integers stored in the variables which are being called through methods

Tags: java, object, variables, methods

The program extracts the digit and I want it to keep looping till the key "Q" / "q" is typed by the user. For example when the user hits the "O" key, the program should print the ones digit of the number they inputted and so on for any 3-digit number the user inputs. I have created methods to extract the ones, tens, and hundreds digit and stored them into variables in a separate class but when I try printing those numbers, nothing prints in the console.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Methods { 

public Methods (int value) {}

public int hundreds (int num) {
    int hund = (num /100)%10;
    return hund;
}

public int tens (int num) {
    int ten = (num / 10)%10;
    return ten;
}

public int ones (int num) {
    int one = num % 10;
    return one;
}
}


public class DigitExtractor {


public static void main(String[] args)
        throws java.io.IOException {



    char input = ' '; //initialize outside loop
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Input an integer");
    int wholeNumber = s.nextInt();
    Methods num = new Methods(wholeNumber);


    do {
        System.out.println("show (W)hole number.");
        System.out.println("show (O)nes place number.");
        System.out.println("show (T)ens place number.");
        System.out.println("show (H)undreds place number.");
        System.out.println("(Q)uit");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
        input = s.next().trim().charAt(0); //using scanner only


        if (wholeNumber == 'W' || wholeNumber == 'w') {
            System.out.println("The whole number is: " + wholeNumber);
        } else if (wholeNumber == 'O' || wholeNumber == 'o') {
            System.out.println("The ones place digit is: " + num.ones(wholeNumber));
        } else if (wholeNumber == 'T' || wholeNumber == 't') {
            System.out.println("The tens place digit is: " + num.tens(wholeNumber));
        } else if (wholeNumber == 'H' || wholeNumber == 'H') {
            System.out.println("The hundreds place digit is: " + num.hundreds(wholeNumber));
        }
    } while ((wholeNumber != 'q') && (wholeNumber != 'Q'));
}
```

}

Comment: I do not see where you are updating 'keyboard' with new input.  Can you paste some output?  Some other odd things: You pass an integer into your DigitExtractor constructor, but don't do anything with it.  You seem to define the ones,tens, hudnreds methods inside the Methods class.  I don't see how those could be called as "num.ones(integer)" as they aren't defined in the DigitExtractor class.

Comment: Check the code now, I took out the keyboard and just use one scanner variable @Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some issues that need to be resolved in order for it to work:

- The `Method` class must be outside of the `DigitExtractor` class.
- The methods you call in the loop are of the `Methods` class, so the
  constructor you have to instantiate is `Methods`.
- You have to capture the keyboard inputs from the variable `input`.
- Extra: You need to surround your code with try/catch.

I made minimal corrections of your code and it works with this version:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DigitExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)){

            System.out.print("Input an integer");
            int integer = input.nextInt();
            Methods num = new Methods(integer);
            char keyboard;

            do {
                System.out.println("show (W)hole number.");
                System.out.println("show (O)nes place number.");
                System.out.println("show (T)ens place number.");
                System.out.println("show (H)undreds place number.");
                System.out.println("(Q)uit");
                System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
                keyboard = input.next().charAt(0);

                if (keyboard == 'W' || keyboard == 'w') {
                    System.out.println("The whole number is: " + integer);
                } else if (keyboard == 'O' || keyboard == 'o') {
                    System.out.println("The ones place digit is: " + num.ones(integer));
                } else if (keyboard == 'T' || keyboard == 't') {
                    System.out.println("The tens place digit is: " + num.tens(integer));
                } else if (keyboard == 'H' || keyboard == 'H') {
                    System.out.println("The hundreds place digit is: " + num.hundreds(integer));
                }
            } while ((keyboard != 'q') && (keyboard != 'Q'));
        }
    }
}

class Methods { 

    public Methods (int value) {}

    public int hundreds (int num) {
        return (num /100)%10;
    }

    public int tens (int num) {
        return (num / 10)%10;
    }

    public int ones (int num) {
        return num % 10;
    }
}
```